# Cannot use .place command for tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I use .place command to indicate the place of "TEXT" (100, 70), but cannot reflect in the window even if changing it to any coordinate.

Could you specify the problem?

```py
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.create_widgets()
        self.master.geometry("600x300")

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.msg1 = tk.Label(self, text = "TEXT")
        self.msg1.place(x = 100, y = 70)
        self.msg1.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master = root)
    app.mainloop()
```

[image]

Comment: Why ```self.msg1.pack()``` after ```self.msg1.place(...)```? ```.pack()``` geometry manager is over riding the ```place``` geometry manager

Answer (score 1):

Few corrections to make:

1. Don't use `.pack()` geometry manager after `.place` geometry manager, or `pack()` will over ride `.place()` manager:

```
def create_widgets(self):
    self.msg1 = tk.Label(self, text = "TEXT")
    self.msg1.place(x = 100, y = 230)
```

2. Use `fill` and `expand` parameter to pack the Frame:

```
self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
```

Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH,expand=1)
        self.create_widgets()
        self.master.geometry("600x300")

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.msg1 = tk.Label(self, text = "TEXT")
        self.msg1.place(x = 100, y = 230)
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master = root)
    app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use both `.pack()` and `.place()`, use one of them instead.

Let's say to use `.place()`:

```
import tkinter as tk

class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.create_widgets()
        self.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)
        self.master.geometry("600x300")

    def create_widgets(self):
        self.msg1 = tk.Label(self, text = "TEXT")
        self.msg1.place(x = 100, y = 70)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Application(master = root)
    app.mainloop()
```

I replaced `self.pack()` with `self.place(relwidth = 1, relheight = 1)`, so the frame will be always wide as the window.

Then I deleted `self.msg1.pack()`.

Now it should work.